# Understanding A Coequalizer in $\mathbf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory, quotient-spaces

From pg. 64 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

[image]

If 
$$
E = \{(fx, gx) \mid x \in X \} \subset Y \times Y,
$$

I can see how $[\text{im}(f) \cup \text{im}(g)] / E$ makes sense, but might not $Y / E$ fail to make sense since there might be elements in $Y$ that aren't related by $E$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an equivalence relation $E$ on a set $Y$, all $(y,y)$ are elements of $E$. So to construct the least equivalence relation containing some relation $R$ we must (i) throw in all $(y,y)$ for $y\in Y$, (ii) all $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ where $(x,y)\in R$ and (iii) all $(x,z)$ when we already have $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)\in R$.

Comment: Oh, that's what the author meant by "least equivalence relation". It's the one that's generated from the $\{ (fx, gx) \}$.

Comment: @user1770201 Exactly!

Comment: To be sure you know an "algebraic structure" generated by a subset,all elements are generated in finite steps: take equivalence relation as an example,  to form the least equivalence relation containing some subset you have to add all diagonal elements and all elements that are symmetric to the given subset. Then we have to add $(x,z)$ if you already have $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$, but all elements are added in finite steps: prove that  all elements that are added in finite steps is enough to be an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2):

Well let us look at an example. Let $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $Y = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and let $f(x) = 2x - 1$ and $g(x) = x$. Then $E$ is the smallest relation on $Y \times Y$ containing the relations $1E1$, $3E2$,and $5E3$. Since $E$ needs to be reflexive, we add in $xEx$ for all $x \in Y$. Since $E$ needs to be symmetric, we add it $2E3$ and $3E5$. Since $E$ needs to be transitive, we add in $2E5$ (since $2E3E5$) and its reverse of course.

Thus the equivalence classes of $E$ are $[1] = \{1\}$, $[2] = \{2,3,5\}$ and $[4] = \{4\}$.